# Property [description] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance

Tags: laravel

Disculpen tengo una duda con respecto al método pluck...

Y es que, cuando mostrar algunas propiedades de un Objeto, me genera este error.

> Exception Property [title] does not exist on this collection instance.
> (View:
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel\sordostest\resources\views\question\index.blade.php)

```
public function index($exam_id){
    $exams = Exam::orderBy('id', 'ASC')->where('id', $exam_id)->pluck('id', 'title');

    $questions = Question::where('exam_id', $exam_id)->get();
    
    dd($exams);
    return view('question.index',  compact('exams','questions', 'exam_id'));
  }
```

Sin embargo, al hacer un `dd()` me arroja lo siguiente:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1249 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    "Examen 1" => 1
  ]
}
```

Y, a la lineá que se refiere el error es esta:

```
<div class="card-header text-center">Preguntas del examen: {{$exams->title}}></div>
```

Estuve debugeando y si arroja los datos correctamente, sin embargo, laravel me sigue diciendo que title no existe en esa colección.

Comment: Al pasarle dos parámetros a pluck de esa manera, se retorna el id + tittle, por ende el resultado en el dd() es correcto. Quizá debas utilizar select() para hacer lo que quieres

Comment: También intente con select, de esta manera `$exams = Exam::select('id', 'title')->where('id', $exam_id)->get();` sin embargo, el error persistia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ese error lo obtienes por que en la vista estas intentando acceder a los valores de `$exams` como si de un objeto se tratara, cuando de hecho el método `pluck` lo que te retorna es un array.

Entonces lo que tienes que hacer es iterar dicho array para acceder e imprimir los valores.

Partiendo entonces de tu consulta de esta forma:

```
$exams = Exam::orderBy('id', 'ASC')->whereId($exam_id)->pluck('id', 'title');
```

Y con una supuesta salida de esta forma:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1186 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    "titulo 1" => 1
    "titulo 2" => 2
    "titulo 3" => 4
  ]
}
```

Entonces deberías iterar de esta forma:

```
foreach ($exams as $title => $value) {
    echo $value.'-'.$title;
}
```

Sin embargo noto (*al menos por lo que muestra tu consulta*) solo planeas obtener un valor de un registro como en este caso el título, de ser esto así como lo entiendo entonces:

- Puedes recomponer la consulta de esta forma:

  ```
  $exams = Exam::orderBy('id')->whereId($exam_id)->value('title');
  ```

Como notas con el método <sup>2</sup>[**`value`**](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#retrieving-results) indico lo que deseo obtener de esta consulta, hago el <sup>1</sup>ordenamiento por la columna de `id` (*y no necesito pasarle en este caso el segundo argumento, dado que lo necesitas `ASC` y este es el valor que por defecto usará el método*).

Entonces en la vista puedes simplemente imprimir el título de esta forma:

```
<div class="card-header text-center">Preguntas del examen: {{ $exams }}></div>
```

**Revisa las definiciones de los métodos en**

- <sup>1</sup>Método `orderBy()`: `app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder.php`
- <sup>2</sup>Método `value`: `app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder.php`

Comment: En efecto, solo me interesa saber los títulos de cada examen, para mostrarlo al usuario. Gracias, ya funciono.

Comment: Si, ya se lo quite. ¡Gracias!.

Comment: Ah propósito, si deseo tambien obtener el id, ¿modificaria el value de esta manera('id', ',title'); ?

Comment: ¿Algo así? `$exams = Exam::orderBy('id')->whereId($exam_id)->select('id', 'title');`

Comment: Debería quedar así `Exam::Select('id', 'title')->whereId($exam_id)->orderBy('id')->first();` y luego sin iterar accedes así `$variable->id;`